Validator reports 0 own stake
Validator reports 0 own stake, which shouldn't be the case. https://joystream.subscan.io/validator/j4V34YfStojh9yWCXVmv5bwR4rV4nHwvJLRqCF39acoVPnJiB?tab=nominator
When I query staking.ledger for controller account I get proper values:
total: 1,686,109,440,000,301
active: 1,686,109,440,000,301
But if I query staking.erasStakers for current era (1912), then it reports 0 own stake:
total: 33,350,429,564,755,056
own: 0
Any ideas what is going on?
